# prevent visual studio from reverting the Resource designer properties in to internal

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resource-files

I know the resource designer files are auto generated, we are achieving WPF localization through resource files at project level. And its possible only if we have the resource designer properties as public qualified. Now any time i add a new resx entry, all the properties get modified to "internal" scope! Is there any setting, attribute i can add to prevent this? any help is gr8! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you hand editing the text file? If not, there must be an "Access Modifier" drop down when you open the Resource through Resource Editor. I hope Visual Studio will preserve your selection, if you pick the "Public" value from that drop down.

Comment: i was selectively marking few properties as public, as not all were used in localization! But i bet marking the resource file itself as public, should make my life easier!